# How to add to a map who's type is of another struct?

Tags: go, struct

```
type Email struct { 

    From string
    To string
    Body string

}

type User struct {

    Inbox map[string]Email
    Outbox map[string]Email

}
```

How do I add a value to the User Map/Initialise?? I'm extremely confused,  I can add to the User map if it was not type Email, but it is extremely confusing.

Comment: What exactly is confusing? What did you try?

Comment: Start with the go tour - and this section: https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/19

Answer (score 1):

`map` values are nil by default, unless you initialize them via `make`. So to save yourself some boilerplate, create a "constructor" for any type that has a map to do this initialization for you e.g.

```
func newUser() User {
    return User{
        Inbox:  make(map[string]Email),
        Outbox: make(map[string]Email),
    }
}
```

To use:

```
u := newUser()
u.Inbox["gmail#56"] = Email{
    From: "me",
    To:   "you",
    Body: "how are you?",
}
u.Outbox["outlook#25"] = Email{
    From: "Mr. Smith",
    To:   "Bossman",
    Body: "report is done?",
}
```

Playground example: https://play.golang.org/p/3LLurNsDJER

---

You can also initialized maps inline, but the syntax is quite tedious:

```
u := User{
    Inbox:  map[string]Email{"gmail": Email{From: "me", To: "you", Body: "how are you?"}},
    Outbox: map[string]Email{"outlook": Email{From: "Mr. Smith", To: "Bossman", Body: "report is done?"}},
}
```